# Click Once Setup.exe returns 404 with IIS

Tags: clickonce

Whenever I try to install a Click Once application, I always get a 404 error from the setup.exe file. I've checked the physical folder the web server points to and confirmed that setup.exe exists at the correct location.

The CO deployment also works fine if I open the web page using file://path/to/index.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recording The Answer for myself so I can look it up later

In IIS, check to make sure that in the folder's Properties, Home Directory Tab, Application Settings section, that it is running Scripts Only and not Scripts and Executables.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using IIS 7 or later, go to **Handler Mappings** feature, and remove **CGI** mapping. Then your *setup.exe* will served as usual static file.

Comment: Thanks! and even if it's disabled - delete it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's now ok for me

Answer (score 5):

In the website properties in IIS on the Home Directory tab make sure you've set execute permissions to Script only and **NOT** to Script and Executables.

Comment: Did you vote down my answer just to make yours appear closer to the top, even though they are the same answer with the exception that I got the tab wrong (minor) and you want me to apply the setting to the entire website instead of the specific directory (which could break other parts of the site).

Comment: No I didn't, I was just trying to help with your problem by providing an awnser.

Comment: You need a rep of at least a 100 to downvote take a look at mine. Have a nice day.